# how to build a display in 2d for a game

Tags: c++, 2d, graphic

I am building a project for university. It's a snake game. I've built tools in c++ to move snake, to generate "food" for snake etc.

Now how to build 2d display to move everything I've built so far and create this simple game. Ive found these links but they were not helpful.

http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/14064/

Comment: Have you looked into [SDL](https://www.libsdl.org/)?

Comment: Yes. Reading the documentation now. What do I have to look into?

Comment: A simple Google search with something like "Your first SDL game" will bring up dozens of hits on tutorials on making a simple SDL game. Pick one, go through it, and then you'll have a better feel about how to develop your game with it. :)

Comment: Tnx this helped me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Two libraries that are often used for this kind of thing are:

SDL - https://www.libsdl.org

SFML - http://www.sfml-dev.org

My personal favorite is SFML, but both work fine and alternatives also exist.

Comment: I've read instructions but I see this error
http://prntscr.com/bhywgy